# Using getchar in C to store user input of multiple characters

Tags: c, string, char, getchar, cs50

As a rookie, I've been following the Harvard CS50 course. At one point it demonstrates a C program which has users enter their name and then displays a basic greeting containing this input. However, the CS50 demo seems to use a special line in the preamble that enables use of strings in C with "string" and "GetString()".

Without this, I've instead been trying to use getchar():

```
#include<stdio.h>



main(int argc, char *argv[]) 

{

    printf("What's your name? ");    
    char name = getchar();  
    printf("Hello %c!\n", name);
    printf("You're looking cool today.\n");


}
```

I get the first character back from whatever the user puts in as I should, but if I try to lengthen this to to a char array for the whole string with char name[] I get an "incorrect initialisation" error at compile. Yet everywhere I've seen mention of getchar(), increasing the array capacity like this seems to be the solution. I've also seen use of strcpy online, but I've been unable to make this work.

Am I overlooking something really mind-blowingly simple? Any insight appreciated on this, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should stick to the <cs50.h> include file and use their string methods as long as the course uses it and go deeper into C when the course does. You can find the header and relevant information here: [https://manual.cs50.net/library/](https://manual.cs50.net/library/)

Comment: Would you like to show us the code you tried that gave you the "incorrect initialization" error, so perhaps we can tell you what's wrong with it and how to fix it?

Comment: It's complicated in C to do user input robustly; the purpose of the `cs50.h` functions you mention is to free up the novice from having to learn all the intricacies of C user input, and let them get on with writing programs that work.  Once the student is more familiar with the language , then they can go back and look at this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's good to know that user input code isn't trivial! I'll continue following the lessons further until I better my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a fundamental confusion between two data types.

```
char
```

is a single byte character - it can store just one character, and when you print (as you do) with the `%c` format specifier, the byte is turned into a single character on your screen. That is OK as long as you are James Bond, and you colleagues are Q, M, etc.

In my world, people often have longer names. These are represented with a character *array* :

```
char name[100];
```

would be such an array, with enough space for 99 characters plus the terminating `'\0'`. Reading keyboard input into a character array is a notoriously difficult thing to do - because if you do it wrong, the program will crash or worse (buffer overflow leads to undefined behavior).  One (my preferred) way to avoid this is to use the `fgets` function - this specifies not only where the input should go, but how much space was allocated there:

```
char name[100];
printf("what is your name?\n");
fgets(name, 100, stdin);
printf("hello %s\nLooking spiffy!\n", name);
```

As you can see, `fgets` takes three arguments: the buffer, the size of the buffer, and the input stream. The name `stdin` is defined to be the standard input buffer (the keyboard, unless you did some tricky stuff which you will learn about later). Note - you pass the value of `100` but only 99 characters will be read (the 100th space is used for the nul termination).

Answer (score 1):

The error is compiler dependent. Some compilers give error. My compiler didn't (Dev C++).
In my case, it neglected the rest of the input characters and utilised the first entered character.